# Android: Disabling UDP Checksumming

Tags: java, android, sockets, java-native-interface

I know that in Linux, I can disable UDP checksumming with the socket option `SO_NO_CHECK`.  However, in the Android references, I can find neither `SO_NO_CHECK` nor a similar option to disable checksumming.  I understand that I might be able to use JNI to directly access the hardware, however, I'm not real familar with working through the JNI (although I'm much stronger with C/C++ than Java) so I'm hoping there is some, maybe undocumented way, to simply "pass down" the socket option.

So my questions:

1. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?  Maybe one outside both the Android API and JNI?
2. If the JNI is the only option, any names of or links to similar solutions, or small JNI modules inside Android projects that you know of would be much appreciated :-)

Thanks!